# What is wrong with this model?

Tags: modeling, mesh, rigging

I have created a shark for Augmented Reality purposes and I wanted to have the sharks mouth open, I have created a rig and weight painted it correctly (as far as I can tell) but once exported the mouth deforms in the wrong way. Can anyone offer any advice?

[image]

Comment: Where is the model?

Comment: Sorry just added it @LeoNas

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=4145" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/4145/)